# How to set Write permission on a folder for Everyone Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, permissions, share

I am trying to share a folder with everyone and using the below command but it is not working.

```
NET SHARE Movies=C:\foldername  "/GRANT:Everyone,FULL"
```

After runnign this command a message comes 'Movies Shared Successfully' but When i check folder permission it does not show the same.

Can anyone tell me the correct command?

Comment: If *it is not working*, then *what exactly* happens? No share is created at all, wrong permissions are being set, an error message is being risen, something else?

Comment: As written, this has nothing to do with PowerShell or even programming. It would be better on Server Fault.

Comment: vonPryz,

After execution of the command in powershell, messgae comes "Movies shared Successfully" but when i check to the folder it does not show the permission for everyone.

Arloc,

I have tried this command with Command prompt the below command
cacls C:\FolderName /t /e /g Everyone:f

and it runs successfully.

But i want to share the folder with Powershell Command

Answer (score 36, accepted):

your net share works just fine. To set the folder permissions you need to set the ACL permissions:

```
$sharepath = "C:\foldername"
$Acl = Get-ACL $SharePath
$AccessRule= New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("everyone","FullControl","ContainerInherit,Objectinherit","none","Allow")
$Acl.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
Set-Acl $SharePath $Acl
```

You will notice that "Everyone" will show up with full access permissions on the security tab of the folder.